# How to validation login in android project?

Tags: java, android, validation, authentication, android-volley

I have developed one login form in Android. I have to implement validation part to my login class.  This is my login class. I'm using api for connect the db. Please help me this.

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;
SoapPrimitive resultString;
String Response;
String url = "url";

private EditText usernamee;
private EditText passwordd;
private View mLoginFormView;
String username = "";
String password = "";
String response = "";
private String count = "";

JSONArray LocArray = new JSONArray();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final Context context = getApplicationContext();
    // Set up the login form.
    usernamee = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernamee);
    passwordd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordd);

    Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            username = usernamee.getText().toString();
            password = passwordd.getText().toString();

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

            StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            // response
                            Log.d("Response", response);

                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                                if(obj.get("Role").equals("Admin"))
                                {
                                    Intent adminIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                                    startActivity(adminIntent);
                                }
                                else if (obj.get("Role").equals("User"))
                                {
                                    Intent userIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Main3Activity.class);
                                    startActivity(userIntent);
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // error
                            Log.d("Error.Response", response);
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("username", username);
                    params.put("password", password);

                    return params;
                    //return null;
                }
            };
            queue.add(postRequest);

        }
    });


}
```

//    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)

}

How can I implement validation in my login class.

Comment: what do you want to validate? is it to validate if the user has entered valid email and password in the client side or if the they are valid login credentials?

Comment: Yes sir, I need valid email and password

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
      private EditText input_email,input_password;

    public boolean validate() {
                boolean valid = true;

                String email = input_email.getText().toString();
                String password = input_password.getText().toString();

                if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
                    input_email.setError("enter a valid email address");
                    valid = false;
                } else {
                    input_email.setError(null);
                }

                if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
                    input_password.setError("between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters");
                    valid = false;
                } else {
                    input_password.setError(null);
                }

                return valid;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String email = usernamee.getText().toString().trim();
            String pass = passwordd.getText().toString().trim();


            if (pass.length() < 6) {
                edtPass.setError("Password must contain 6  characters");
                edtPass.requestFocus();
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
                edtPass.setError("Please enter Password");
                edtPass.requestFocus();
            }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            edtEmail.setError("Please enter Valid email");
            edtEmail.requestFocus();
        }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                edtEmail.setError("Please enter Usee Name");
                edtEmail.requestFocus();
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) &&
                    pass.length() >= 6 &&
                    Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches() &&
                    !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {

                //call your login service here
            }


        }
    });
```